# Distinct embeddings of $U(n)$ in $U(n+1)$

Tags: lie-groups, quotient-spaces

I want to find the identifications of the quotient spaces for the following identifications of $U(n) \hookrightarrow U(n+1)$

Consider the inclusion given by $i_1$,

$i_1: A \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & & & \\
\vdots & & A & \\
0 & & & 
\end{pmatrix}$
which yields $U(n+1)/U(n) \cong \mathbb{S}^{2n-1}$

Consider the inclusion given by $i_2$,

$i_2: A \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
(\det(A))^{-1} & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & & & \\
\vdots & & A & \\
0 & & & 
\end{pmatrix}$
where we have $U(n+1)/U(n) \cong \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}(n+1)$

> I would like to know why in the first case it gives us $ \mathbb{S}^{2n - 1} $ and in the other case $ \mathbb{S}^{1} \times \mathbb{CP} (n-1) $
>   I understand that in the second case you have to $ i_2(U(n)) \subseteq SU(n + 1) $

Answer (score 1):

$U(n+1)$ acts transitively on the 1-sphere in $\mathbf{C}^{n+1}$, with stabilizer $U(n)$ (embedded by $i_1$). This gives an identification of $U(n+1)/i_1(U(n))$ to rather the sphere $S^{2n+1}$.

Also it acts on the projective space $P_\mathbf{C}^n$, and also acts on the 1-sphere by $g\cdot z=\det(g)z$. For $n\neq 0$ this yields a transitive action on the product $P_\mathbf{C}^n\times S^1$, whose point stabilizer is $S(U(n)\times U(1))=i_2(U(n))$. This gives an identification of $U(n+1)/i_2(U(n)$ to $P_\mathbf{C}^n\times S^1$.